# (Eclipse) Syntax Highlighting Plugin, odd issues with getting started on highlighting/validation

Tags: eclipse, validation, plugins, syntax, highlighting

I'm making a syntax highlighting plugin for my company. I'm not making a new editor, I am using an eclipse template that uses the Extensions for generic editor.

*Disclaimer: I've had a lot of trouble getting XText to work consistently on 3 different machines due to versioning issues, missing files etc. so that's out of the question*

```
org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.presentationReconcilers
org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentTypes
org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.hoverProviders
org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors
org.eclipse.ui.editors
org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.documentSetup
```

I'm using I'm having some odd issues. Before I get started:

- The plugin is detected in Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Plugins 
  Other sample plugins run using the same method i used to run this plugin

**Problems:**

- I'm getting the following error message when placing any content in
  the file except `<?xml version='1.0'>`:

  > "Content is not allowed in Prolog"
- The keywords seem to be highlighted in Blue. As you can see in my
  source code, they should be highlighted in red.

  [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCCho.png)  to view what my runtime Eclipe editor looks like
  when i'm trying to test my syntax rules.

Below are my classes source code.
I'm wondering:

1. why my keywords are being recognized in syntax coloring but are
       invalid commands with that "*prolog*" error above
2. Why the prolog errors above are occurring
3. Why it's validating the file not to my specification or to a different specification
4. Point me in the right direction

Hope you can help.
Thanks :).

Reconciler Class:

```
package myplugin;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.DefaultDamagerRepairer;


public class MyReconciler extends PresentationReconciler {

    public MyReconciler() {
        // TODO this is logic for .project file to color tags in blue. Replace with your language logic!
        MyScanner scanner = new MyScanner(new SyntaxColorProvider());

        DefaultDamagerRepairer dr= new DefaultDamagerRepairer(scanner);
        this.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
        this.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

Scanner class:

```
package myplugin;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List; 

import org.eclipse.jface.text.TextAttribute; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.BufferedRuleBasedScanner; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.EndOfLineRule; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.IRule; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.IToken;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.IWordDetector;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.MultiLineRule;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.PatternRule; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.SingleLineRule; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.Token; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.WhitespaceRule; 
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.WordRule; 


public class MyScanner extends BufferedRuleBasedScanner 
{ 

private static String[] misc = {
     true",
    "false", 
    "unsigned",
    "jump",
    "read",     
    "write",
};

// Tokens
private final IToken KEYWORD_TOKEN;

private List<IRule> basicRules;

public MyScanner(SyntaxColorProvider colorProvider)
{
    super(5000);

    // CREATE TOKENS
    KEYWORD_TOKEN = new Token(new TextAttribute(colorProvider.getColor(SyntaxColorProvider.KEYWORD)));

    // CREATE RULES
    List rules = new ArrayList<IRule>();


    // Add rule for strings and character constants.
    rules.add(new SingleLineRule("\"", "\"", STRING_TOKEN, '\\'));
    rules.add(new SingleLineRule("'", "'", STRING_TOKEN, '\\'));

    // Add word rule for keywords, types, and constants.
    WordRule wordRule = new WordRule(new WordDetector(), OTHER_TOKEN);

    // Single-line comments
    rules.add(new EndOfLineRule("//", STRING_TOKEN));

    // Multi-line comments
    rules.add(new MultiLineRule("/$", "$/", COMMENT_TOKEN));

    // KEYWORDS
    for (String misc : misc)
    {
        wordRule.addWord(misc, KEYWORD_TOKEN);
    }
    rules.add(wordRule);

    IRule[] result= new IRule[rules.size()];
    rules.toArray(result);
    setRules(result);
}
```

}

ValidatorDocumentSetupParticipant:

```
package myplugin;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.IDocumentSetupParticipant;
import org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.IDocumentSetupParticipantExtension;
import org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.LocationKind;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.DocumentEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocumentListener;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class ValidatorDocumentSetupParticipant implements IDocumentSetupParticipant, IDocumentSetupParticipantExtension {

    private final class DocumentValidator implements IDocumentListener {
        private final IFile file;
        private IMarker marker;

        private DocumentValidator(IFile file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void documentChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
            if (this.marker != null) {
                try {
                    this.marker.delete();
                } catch (CoreException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                this.marker = null;
            }
            try (StringReader reader = new StringReader(event.getDocument().get());) {
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(reader));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    this.marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
                    this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                    this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, ex.getMessage());
                    if (ex instanceof SAXParseException) {
                        SAXParseException saxParseException = (SAXParseException)ex;
                        int lineNumber = saxParseException.getLineNumber();
                        int offset = event.getDocument().getLineInformation(lineNumber - 1).getOffset() + saxParseException.getColumnNumber() - 1;
                        this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
                        this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, offset);
                        this.marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, offset + 1);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void documentAboutToBeChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(IDocument document) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(IDocument document, IPath location, LocationKind locationKind) {
        if (locationKind == LocationKind.IFILE) {
            IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(location);
            document.addDocumentListener(new DocumentValidator(file));
        }
```

WordDetector Class:

```
 package myplugin;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.IWordDetector; 

public class WordDetector implements IWordDetector 
{    
    public boolean isWordPart(char character) {
        return Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(character);
    }

    public boolean isWordStart(char character) {
        return Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(character);
    }
}
```

SyntaxColorProvider Class:

```
package myplugin;

import java.util.HashMap; 

public class SyntaxColorProvider 
{ 

public static final RGB RED = new RGB(200, 0, 0); 

public static final RGB GREEN = new RGB(0, 200, 0); 

public static final RGB BLUE = new RGB(0, 0, 200); 

public static final RGB COMMENT = new RGB(128, 128, 128);  

public static final RGB KEYWORD = new RGB(255, 0, 0); 

public static final RGB TYPE = new RGB(0, 0, 128); 

public static final RGB STRING = new RGB(0, 128, 0); 

public static final RGB DEFAULT = new RGB(0, 0, 0); 


protected Map fColorTable = new HashMap(10); 

/**
 * Release all of the color resources held onto by the receiver. 
 */ 
public void dispose() 
{ 
    Iterator e = fColorTable.values().iterator(); 
    while (e.hasNext()) 
        ((Color) e.next()).dispose(); 
} 

/**
 * Return the Color that is stored in the Color table as rgb. 
 */ 
public Color getColor(RGB rgb) 
{ 
    Color color = (Color) fColorTable.get(rgb); 
    if (color == null) 
    { 
        color = new Color(Display.getCurrent(), rgb); 
        fColorTable.put(rgb, color); 
    } 
    return color; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the sample editor with some changes -  and

```
documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(reader));
```

would be parsing XML, perhaps. It detects improper XML because the prolog  is missing. Remove that line from the code, or implement something that flags up and marks issues similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've struggled with the same probelm the function that makes this problem is in this line: `documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(reader));`, Im in the middle of trying to figure out a text parser by myself.